# refreshing fb IFRAME in IE 9 - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I have a problem with refreshing FB Iframe.

It works fine in Mozila and chrome but not in IE 9.

Can you please advise me what I have to do?

Thanks!

I use the following code in order to refresh:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                 window.location = window.location.href;

               } else {
                 //console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
               }
             }, {scope: 'publish_stream, email'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have searched far and wide and run across several "fixes" that range from simple to the extremely complex. In the end, simple has won the race.

Add the following line near the top of the parent page and it should take care the problem. I tried several of the more complex fixes. They did NOT solve my problem. Just setting the browser to compatibility mode didn't either surprisingly. Adding this line did. I don't know what IE=Edge means, but it works when none of the other choices for IE=?  seemed to do the job.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Don.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

or:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

also, it would help if you would add what happens when you it fails in IE9, do you get an error message?

Comment: Thanks for your response but it was not resolved. Regarding to the first suggestion - I already have tried, it didn't help. The second suggestion - it causes to pop-up with message - To display the webpage again, the web browser needs to resend the information you've previously submitted.

Comment: do you get any error messages with the first option? (the one that does not work), also what are you trying to do? why do you want to refresh after authentication?

Comment: No, I don't get any error. It seems that the iframe is reloaded but there is no any update, I think it's only rendered the page. I'm trying to refresh the iframe/page itself.

Comment: if you want to refresh the same page you're in now, try document.location.href = document.location.href;
if you are in an iframe and want to refresh the parent, try:
parent.location.href = parent.location.href
what exactly do you expect to see once reloaded? what updates are you looking for?

Comment: I expected to see update of the page. The use should be connected to the page. I don't see any update. The page is getting refreshed but don't really do any update.

Comment: i'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish, but in most cases refreshing the page is not the right approach and usually means that you're doing things wrong.
can you explain what it is you want?  if this is a fb app canvas page, then the users should already be authorized before they get to your page.